# Can't insert sprite into svg

Tags: html, svg

I wan't to insert sprite into my svg. Why this doesn't work?

```
 <svg width="100" height="100">
 <image xlink:href="blank.gif" class="flag flag-ru" x="10" y="10"      height="50" width="50"></image>
</svg>
```

But this work

```
<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-ru" alt="Czech Republic" />
```

I am using [these sprites](https://www.flag-sprites.com/)

How can I make the sprite work in my svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These flag sprites shift `<img>` element's `background-image` via the CSS property `background-position` in order to display different parts of the larger image. Applying this CSS to SVG element `<image>` has no effect because the `<image>` element has no `background-image` or `background-position`.

Comment: so please tell me how can I make the sprite work in my svg?

Comment: You will have to create a `clipPath` for the `<image>` element and play around with the clipPath position and image position to achieve the same effect. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking . And you will have to dig out all the positions for the individual flags from the flag-sprites' CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find proper "pure" svg solution.
Instead I defined additional css class:

```
 .myDiv{
    position: absolute;
  }


<svg width="100" height="100"> 
  <img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-cz myDiv" alt=""  
  style="top:10px; left:10px;"/>
</svg>
```